# Can constexpr and inline functions be re-defined?

Tags: c++, function, inline, constexpr

I am verifying a statement on C++ Primer that:

> Unlinke other functions, inline and constexpr functions may be defined multiple times in the program.

I used two definitions of a constexpr `cfunc()` below, expecting `foo_0()` will call the 1st def while `foo_1()` will call the 2nd def. However the attempt failed with compilation error (in the end). WHy?

```
constexpr int cfunc(){
  return 42;
}

int foo_0(){
  return cfunc();
}

constexpr int cfunc(){
  return 42;
}

int foo_1(){
  return cfunc();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  cout << foo_0() << endl;  
  cout << foo_1() << endl;  

  /* testconstexprfunc2.cpp:24:15: error: redefinition of ‘constexpr int cfunc()’ */
  /* testconstexprfunc2.cpp:16:15: error: ‘constexpr int cfunc()’ previously defined here */

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can remove everything that is not `constexpr`. Only the two defintions are relevant. http://ideone.com/MXMvCh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes unlike other functions, inline and constexpr functions may be defined multiple times in the program. **However, the definitions must match exactly.**

### **Justification according to the standard:**

From *§ 7.1.5/2 The constexpr speciﬁer [dcl.constexpr]:*

> *`constexpr` functions and `constexpr` constructors are implicitly `inline`.*

From *§ 3.2/6  One deﬁnition rule [basic.def.odr]:*

> *There can be more than one deﬁnition of a class type (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), `inline` function with external linkage ...  in a program provided that each deﬁnition
>   appears in a diﬀerent translation unit...*

From *§ 7.1.2/4 Function speciﬁers [dcl.fct.spec]:*

> *An `inline` function shall be deﬁned in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same deﬁnition in every case.*

Thus, since a `constexpr` function is implicitly `inline` it has all the attributes of an `inline` function. Therefore, **`constexpr` functions can have more than one definition provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit**.

### Why your program fails:

In your case the program fails because you are violating this rule. That is, you redefine the same `constexpr` function in the same translation unit (i.e., main.cpp).

Comment: Just curious if there is reference about this?

Comment: @burrito, §7.1.2 [dcl.fct.spec]/4: *An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly
the same definition in every case.*

Comment: It is still unclear though which justification the code in the question violated.

Comment: 3.2/6: inline function with external linkage (7.1.2)

Answer (score 4):

An inline function can be defined multiple times in a program but only once in a translation unit. That means it can be defined only once in a header file. You can't have more than one definition in a translation unit even if they are identical.

Answer (score 2):

It is true - regarding inline functions. This is the case to allow inline functions in a header, in order to make inlining possible at compile-time (instead at link time).

The following citation does not mention `constexpr` at all, but as noted they are implicitly inlined.

The key, as explained by @R Sahu, is `provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit`, which is not the case here.

Citing the standard, §3.2.6:

> There can be more than one definition of (...) inline function with external linkage (7.1.2) (...) in a program **provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit**, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. (...)

Comment: But in the question, the two definition of `cunfc()` matches yet still fails.